# Error in creating service connection in Azure Devop to Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

I am provisioning an AKS cluster version 1.25. In this cluster the localservice account is disabled by default and is advised to keep it so.
My credentials are those of a Contributor and also AKS admnin

But while creating a service connection from Azure Devops environment i keep on getting the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Kubernetes Service connection directly with the Admin account, Unfortunately it is not possible. Refer below:-

> In order to create Service Connections in DevOps, no matter what type of cluster configuration you have, local accounts need to be enabled, otherwise it is not possible to create a DevOps Service Connection.

[Cannot setup a Kubernetes Service Connection without enabling local accounts - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1048362/cannot-setup-a-kubernetes-service-connection-witho) By KarishmaTiwari-MSFT

And creating Azure Kubernetes Service Connection with Azure Subscription gives an error :-

> Could not find any secrets associated with the Service Account.

***As its a known issue. As an Alternative, You can make use of Kubeconfig for your cluster admin or create a service account in your aks with a secret and use it to create a Service connection like below:-***

I deployed one Azure kubernetes cluster and enabled Azure AD and Azure RBAC like below:-

[image]

Added a user as a Kubernetes Cluster Admin :-

[image]

Connect to your Kubernetes Cluster on Azure which is enabled with Azure AD authentication run the following commands in your Azure CLI :-

```bash
 az aks get-credentials --resource-group siliconrg098 --name siliconaks09 --admin
```

Move to the .kube/config file

```bash
 cat /home/siddhesh/.kube/config
```

***Copy the contents from your **kube.config** file and paste it in the Azure DevOps Service connection KubeConfig section like below :-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

***The Azure Kubernetes Service connection got created successfully refer below:-***

[image]

Now, I used the same service connection for Azure Kubernetes task in Azure DevOps like below:-

[image]

**References:-**

[Visual Studio Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/New-Kubernetes-service-connection-causes/10138123#T-N10138393) By Wade Zhou

[AKS with Kubernetes Service Connection returns "Could not find any secrets associated with the Service Account." error in Azure Pipelines - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1051970/aks-with-kubernetes-service-connection-returns-cou) By KarishmaTiwari

Comment: hi i tried the service account approach but the secret isnt created after running the secret yaml.. any guidance here please

Comment: Did you try with ServiceAccount method? For Service Account you need to create secret and service account separetely. Also,  Azure Subscription method will give an error. And what about KubeConfig method as suggested above?

Comment: i want to use the Envrionment tab for creating a service connection this one doesn't have the kubeconfig option.

Comment: i made another question with more details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692230/secret-for-a-kubernetes-service-accounts-is-not-getting-created