# Secret for a Kubernetes service accounts is not getting created

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a kubernetes cluster version 1.26
Here i'm creating  a serviceaccount following the instructions in the yaml given below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
   creationTimestamp: null
   name: devops-serviceaccount
   namespace: default


apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: role-for-serviceaccount
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*","apps","extensions"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]




apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: rolebinding-for-serviceaccount
  namespace: default
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: devops-serviceaccount
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: role-for-serviceaccount
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io


apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: devops-sa-secret
  annotations:
      kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "devops-serviceaccount"
```

after deploying the yaml i run the following command

> kubectl get serviceAccounts devops-serviceaccount

I expect a Service Account with the secrets attached to it but the secret count is 0

[image]

Comment: Please take a moment to properly format your YAML manifests as code samples. They are very difficult to read in their current form.

Comment: updated the yaml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After version K8s **1.24** it does not default to create the secret with a **Service account**. If you are following any article make sure it's not for an older versions of **k8s**.

As you are on **1.26** which is the latest and it does not support **secret** creation by default with SA creation and it wont show.

You can read more about my article : https://medium.com/faun/k8s-v1-24-is-unable-to-create-a-serviceaccount-secret-798f8454e6e7

**Update**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test-sa
secrets:
  - name: token-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
metadata:
  name: token-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: "test-sa"
```

what i found, field counts the **secrets** mentioned in the field with a **service account**.

Code ref of [SA struct](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/c09d01192aa51f9db0457ddb1ae1972326e37e8d/staging/src/k8s.io/api/core/v1/types.go#L4950)

Comment: Hey Harish.. i can see the token is created and the secret to but when i run this command kubectl get serviceAccounts devops-serviceaccount. the secret count is still 0

Comment: upadated answer

Answer (score 0):

The token is of type `Secret`, so you need to list your secrets (`kubectl get secret`).  As of v1.24+, you won't seen your token show up in the SECRETS column of your service account anymore