# azure devops and deploy app in k8s with pipelines (no local accounts)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

I was testing and practicing with azure devops and a kubernetes cluster (AKS)... I have a repository in github and a pipeline in devops which is connected to git, so when I make a change in the git branch it uploads the image in azure regestry and then the automatic deployment in the cluster, but to achieve this I had to activate the local users of the cluster, if not, it gave me an error when making the connection and wanting to search for the namespace.

If I do not activate the local users of the cluster, is it possible for Azure Devops to deploy to K8s?

Thanks !!

I need to create a connection between Azure Devops and my AKS k8s cluster so that when I reach the deployment step I have authorization without the need to activate the local accounts of the cluster.

1.- I tried activating local accounts and the deployment worked perfectly, but it is not what I need for apparently security reasons.

2.- I tried generating a connection from project settings -> service connections and created one type "Azure Account", where previously I had to create a service account and a secret and join them to then obtain the "service-account-secret-name". I saved the connection, but then when trying to configure the pipeline, select the cluster and the namespace it continued to throw me the error:

"Error while fetching cluster credentials. Make sure you have clusterAdmin permissions on the cluster. Error from external server: Failed to query service connection API"

I hope to be able to connect azure devops with my cluster, but not using local accounts, to be able to carry out a deployment

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you are creating a Kubernetes service connection with Service account option.

In the note of  [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#service-account-option), it mentioned

> When using the service account option, [ensure that a RoleBinding exists](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-rolebinding), which grants permissions in the edit ClusterRole to the desired service account. This is needed so that the service account can be used by Azure Pipelines for creating objects in the chosen namespace.

Please check if you have the RoleBinding step.

You can also refer the Method2 in [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/New-Kubernetes-service-connection-causes/10138123#T-N10138393) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75681714/16162444).

Comment: thank you!!! I will read the links that you shared with me

Comment: Thanks, I already deployed my app with CI/CD